# Should Tiagra 4700 use a 10s or 11s chain?

Tags: shimano, chain

Considering that Tiagra 4700, which is a 10 speed groupset that uses 11s spacing (just missing one gear), would I be correct in assuming that it uses an 11 speed chain?

Just picked up a partial Tiagra 10s groupset and am not sure which chain to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It uses 10 speed chains. 4700 takes any applicable Shimano/SRAM 10 cassette. What's different is the RD actuation ratio, which is the same as Shimano road 11. So in other words each shifter click cable travel distance is different from older 10-speed Shimano shifters, and road 11 RDs can replace RD-4700, which again they can't on an older Shimano road 10 bike.

Comment: Ah, so the shifters’ cable pull is special, as in “normal 10s spacing but actuated via the 11s pull ratio”. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The only thing is that it may not special in the future sense. GRX 10 is the same deal. It seems likelier than not that all future 10-speed groups will be the same, i.e. they may never make a non-legacy-support 10-speed STI again with the old actuation rate. This is conjecture but it seems likelier than them going this far and turning back.

Answer (score 4):

Here it might be useful to consider what is different with Tiagra 4700 10-speed and old 10-speed groups.

It's not the cassette spacing, because Tiagra 4700 does not use special cassettes. You can fit any 10-speed Shimano cassette and it will work (subject to the constraints of rear derailleur capacity, big sprocket support and chain length).

It is the rear derailleur and shifter cable pull ratio. The ratio was originally implemented for 11-speed systems because there's slight inaccuracy in cable pull, due to the clearances inside the housing and also due to friction. Old 10-speed groups before the era of internal cable routing and whole-length cable housing had minimal friction and also the 10-speed spacing was not so fine that the inaccuracy wasn't too great.

However, then two things appeared. Both 11-speed groups that have narrower spacing and thus would have less cable pull per shift if they used the 10-speed ratio, and also internal cable routing with whole length housing increased issues due to friction and internal clearances. To make 11-speed internally routed whole-length-housing systems work, Shimano had to change the cable pull ratio at the derailleur and shifter.

Now, the 10-speed Tiagra 4700 groupset also incorporates the new improved cable pull ratio, mainly because it's fashionable today to run whole-length-housing and route the cables inside the frame. The new cable pull ratio makes this internal routing work far better.

There are also other improvements in cable technology: for example Tiagra 4700 should ideally use an Optislick coated inner cable as opposed to a regular stainless one.

So the Tiagra rear derailleur is really an 11-speed compatible one, and the Tiagra shifters are a combination of two systems: 10-speed cassette spacing and 11-speed rear derailleur ratio for a mixed 10/11-speed pull per shift.

So ideally the chain should be a 10-speed chain. 11-speed chain will probably work at the cost of poor shifting. Usually you can fit a too narrow chain, it will fit, but shift poorly. Too wide chain wouldn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either 10 or 11 speed chain on Tiagra 4700 cassette.

Technically, both 10 and 11 speed chain has 11/128" internal width (the width measured between inner link plate). Main different between them is the external width measured around the outer link, 5.88 up to 7 mm for 10 speed chain and 5.5-5.62 mm for 11 speed chain.

You can use 11 speed chain on 10 speed sprocket because the chain is not too narrow for the sprocket. But you should avoid using 10 speed chain on 11 speed sprocket because when the chain is too wide, it can rub against the nearby sprocket creating noise and unnecessary wear.